# Swift Class Initialization Confusion

Tags: ios, swift, class, initialization

I am doing research about class initialization in iOS class initialization.

When I am reading the following code, I am a bit confused about the Swift initialization rules.
Here is the code:

```
struct Sale {
var month:String
var value:Double
}

class DataGenerator {

//Where is the initialization ?

static var randomizedSale: Double {
    return Double(arc4random_uniform(10000) + 1) / 10
}

static func data() -> [Sale] {
    let months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]

    var sales = [Sale]()

    for month in months {
        let sale = Sale(month: month, value: randomizedSale)
        sales.append(sale)
    }

    return sales
}
```

My question is where is the initialization in  `DataGenerator` class?

What I am thinking is, variable `randomizedSale` actually has default value already as the implementation in brackets. So initialization method is not required in this class.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `randomizedSale` is a *computed property,* there is no need (and it makes no sense) to "initialize" it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your question directly: the initialization method is not necessary.

The variable `randomizedSale` is static, so you don't need an instance to use it. It has nothing to do with the initialization.

Since all your variables and functions are static you don't need to write an init method. If create something like:

```
class A { 
    var x: Int
}
```

You will get an error because your variable `x` is not optional and you didn't provide any value for it so you have to write an init OR set an initial value.

```
class A { 
    var x: Int // Write init or set a value here

    init() {
        x = 0
    }
}
```

I strongly recommend you to read the [section about initialization in Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html).

Answer (score 1):

The `DataGenerator` class only has static members. Static members must always be provided with an initial value (either implicit or explicit).

A class without instance variables doesn’t need an initialiser.

Answer (score -2):

You're thinking along the right lines here. So basically, if all properties of `DataGenerator` have a default value, Swift can give it a default initialiser of `init()`. So DataGenerator does have an `init`, you just don't need to write it :)